# C++ Windows fopen() vs _fsopen()

Tags: c++, windows

MSDN for fopen() says " returns a pointer to the open file."  For _fsopen() - " returns a pointer to the stream. ". Both return FILE*.
Can someone explain the difference, if any?

Comment: `_fsopen()`: *Opens a stream with file sharing.*

Comment: Just poorly defined terminology - "file" and "stream" are synonymous here.

Comment: Look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/ *Object type that identifies a stream.*

Comment: It is an alternative for the dangerous fopen(), which allows anybody else to write to the file at the same time.  Also consider fopen_s(), the C11 Annex K alternative that is more likely to be portable.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that [`_fsopen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fsopen-wfsopen?view=vs-2017) takes one extra parameter than `fopen()` and that is `shflag`.

This flag specifies the type of sharing allowed.   You can Permit/Deny the Read/Write to the file in different combinations.